# Disable pagination only for specific category

Tags: categories, pagination

I'm trying, without success, to disable pagination only in a specific category (where I'm showing all the posts of that category listed by years).
Someone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: i need a snippet for all my categories, this only work for one

Comment: @rafikbennacer I converted your solution into a comment, I'm assuming it was intended as a comment, but I couldn't figure out which solution you were commenting on. Don't post comments as solutions to other peoples answers in future though. If you have a different question you should ask it as a new question rather than finding a similar question that's close

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, replacing `my_cat` with your category slug.  This will modify the main query just before rendering the loop on the archive page of your category.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_disable_pagination' );
function wpse_disable_pagination( $query ) {

  if( is_category( 'my_cat' ) {
    query->set( 'posts_per_page', '-1' );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

@bynicolas thanks! One shot, one kill :)

This is the modified sintax of your snippet that worked for me:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_disable_pagination' );
function wpse_disable_pagination( $query )
{
  if ( is_category( 'newsletter' ) )
  $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '-1' );
}
```